# PHP file_get_contents() doesn't load external dynamic content

Tags: php, cross-domain, file-get-contents

I am trying to insert my profile from the external website (url) to my blog.

Cross-domain is prohibited so iframe, AJAX and jquery load don't work. PHP file_get_contents() do but dynamically generated content inside page doesn't load.

Help me to understand why and how can I solve this issue?

I use such code:

```
<head>
  <base href="https://bookmate.com/">
</head>

<?php
  $url = 'https://bookmate.com/kirillmazur/finished';
  echo file_get_contents($url);
?>
```

Comment: Inspect the requests being made in your browser and repeat them using `file_get_contents()`.

Comment: checkout the answer below. they remote site using local path for some js files. if your are using file_get_contents you need to have this local files in your host.

Answer (score 0):

this is due to missing of two javascript file. you can try by adding those two files in to your local directiry

```
  <script src="/javascript/core.js?4417dc0"></script>
  <script src="/javascript/modules.js?4417dc0">
```

check all the missing files in local directory using[image]ing browser console

Comment: That's why I use "<base href...." to let a website know the real address. You can see it here: http://kirillmazur.com/vc/new/bookmate.php So problem still exist.

Comment: use browser console to get use full error message to debug your code.

Comment: I always use browser console and it seems like these errors from your image are not mine :) I think it's one of your chrome plugins (VK. Startup maybe...) generate the error to console because I don't have such errors.

Answer (score 0):

Hope It will help. I had same problem Here is what I did:

I used iframe and javascript to get page with all the dynamically loaded contents

```
  contents =document.getElementById('load_page1').contentWindow.document.documentElement.outerHTML;
```

I loaded the page in iframe

```
<iframe id="load_page1"></iframe>     

 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      var url="www.google.com"
        jQuery('#load_page1').attr('src',url);
});
```

then from Javascript I get contents of that iframe in a variable on button click event and sent it through ajax by encoding it into base64

```
 <input type="button" id="load_css" />


 jQuery(document).on('click',"#load_css",function(){


contents =document.getElementById('load_page1')
   .contentWindow.document.documentElement.outerHTML;
 contents   =   btoa(contents);


jQuery.ajax({
        url:'process.php',
        data:{contents:contents},
        method:"post"}).done(function(data){
                    jQuery('.css_target').html(data);
        });
});
```

and on ajax page I did all the processing thorugh decodeing it back from base64 to string.